# Why do I get different result from geocode api vs google maps

Tags: json, google-geocoder

I am new to google geocode API but I am planning to use the free version to get map coordinates for nearby golf courses. I started with my home course:
[http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Karlstad+golfklubb](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Karlstad%20golfklubb)

Plus "&key=[my generated api key]"

I get a result with status="OK" but the resulting long/lat is not correct. It's near but misses with 7-8km.

When I use maps.google I get correct location. Searched for "Karlstad golfklubb". 
https://www.google.se/maps/place/Karlstad+Golfklubb/@59.4346545,13.5140563,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x465cb41aca8c1467:0x64836d18f18df2f6

Why do I get different geo locations when using the same keywords. Do they operate on different databases or do I need to enter more params?

I also tried with other nearby courses like "sommarro" and "bryngfjorden" but for they I get zero result. But no problem finding them in google maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the JSON code, they describe the formatted_address as

`"formatted_address" : "Karlstad Golfbanan Jako, 652 30 Karlstad, Sweden"`

Which if you enter into Google Maps shows the correct longitude and latitude in the JSON.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Karlstad+Golfbanan+Jako,+Sweden/@59.3602394,13.472185,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x465cb23bc0f46911:0x66ceae446bdc95dc

Comment: Yes. But that is not the golf course I am looking for. Thats the address for Sommarro golf course.

Comment: @SGoldwin yeah I'm not entirely sure how up to date their API is. It's possible they might not have it in the geocode API system yet. I tried going [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) and entering that golf course into their example and it doesn't come up :/

Comment: that should explain why I don't get any result for the other courses. Then it would be interesting to know when their geocode API system has all the data that google maps has.

Comment: I tried Microsoft Bing location API and it worked better. I got correct coordinates for nearby golf courses. Perhaps I use their API instead.